# How can I update a control on another thread?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, user-interface, instance

This is my situation, I have one button on my form.

When I click it, I want a new instance of MyNewClass to make a Picturebox appear on my form.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fooThread As New Threading.Thread(Sub() Foo())
        fooThread.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Foo()
        Dim myInstance = New MyNewClass()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyNewClass
    Public Sub New()
        Dim testControl = New PictureBox()
        testControl.BackColor = Color.Green
        Form1.Controls.Add(testControl)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is, when I click the button, nothing appears.
I've tried using an Invoke method in order to add the initialized picturebox to Form1 controls:

```
        Form1.Invoke(Sub() Form1.Controls.Add(testControl))
```

but then when I click Button1, I get an exception :
`Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created`

Thanks for helping

Comment: Why would you be creating the control on a different thread in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that YourNewClass doesn't know Form1 as you expected. You must introduce it in global variable. This Code will work:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyForm = Me
    Dim fooThread As New Threading.Thread(Sub() Foo())
    fooThread.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Foo()
    Dim myInstance = New MyNewClass()
End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyNewClass
    Public Sub New()
        Dim testControl = New PictureBox()
        testControl.BackColor = Color.Green
        MyForm.Invoke(Sub() MyForm.Controls.Add(testControl))
    End Sub
End Class

Public Module Module1
    Public MyForm As Form
End Module
```